# How can I position my dropdown menu where I want it to be?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

There is something strange going on with my dropdown menu.  In my navbar I have two dropdown menus, one is the user's menu and the other one is the notification menu.  The user's menu is working just fine, however, the notification one, when I click on it, its dropdown shows to the left of my site.  When I add `dropdown-menu-right` to it, it moves to the right, but it is sticking to the right.  Is there a way I can place the dropdown below the "chat" bubble icon? (I'm using Bootstrap 4).

This is what's happening if I don't add `dropdown-menu-right` to my html:
[image]

This is what happens if I add `dropdown-menu-right` to my html:
[image]

This is my notification's dropdown html

```
    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle user-menu-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" 
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu message-notification-dropdown dropdown-menu-right">
            <div>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Message 1</a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
      </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing my html, I realized I had misplaced my dropdown menu.  I apologize for not noticing this before.